# Perverse incentive for Rapport hat

Tags: discussion, behavior, winter-bash-2021

For this year's Winter Bash, the Consensus, Rapport and Harmony hats all require eight *consecutive* reviews where the majority of users agree with you.

However, I have seen many questions where the OP has edited their post to include more context, yet there are still 3 votes which is a majority (5 votes required to close).  These questions should definitely be left open, yet choosing "Leave Open" will hinder users' chances of getting these badges.

Given the importance of the meta queues to maintaining the quality standards and order of SE sites, it is abhorrent that this behaviour has been encouraged by these hats. It is against the spirit of discouraging [soul-selling for hats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288493/discouraging-soul-selling-for-hats).

So could this trigger not be reused for future years? At the very least, it would be better to remove the consecutive part and increase the number of reviews so that one review does not affect the chances of getting the streak.

Comment: Agreed. These hats break the reviewing process. There is no point in having 5 users review an item if they have a strong incentive to just agree with the other reviewers.